# Send Button in Serial

Tags: c#

I want to make RC and remote it using serial communication. I want to:

- if i press 'W' in keyboard, send '1000'
- if i press 'S' in keyboard, send '0100'
- if i press 'A' in keyboard, send '0010'
- if i press 'D' in keyboard, send '0001'
- if i press 'W' and 'A', send '1010'
- if i press 'W' and 'D', send '1001'
- etc, just like we play a game

I make a code, but it didn't work when I press A and W together. The code didn't send '1010', but only send '1000'

```
private void SEND_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    string tx;
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.W & e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.A)
    {
        tx = "1010";
        serialPort1.Write(tx);
    }
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.W & e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.D)
    {
        tx = "1001";
        serialPort1.Write(tx);
    }
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.S & e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.A)
    {
        tx = "0110";
        serialPort1.Write(tx);
    }
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.W & e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.A)
    {
        tx = "0101";
        serialPort1.Write(tx);
    }
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.W)
    {
        tx = "1000";
        serialPort1.Write(tx);
    }
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.S)
    {
        tx = "0100";
        serialPort1.Write(tx);
    }
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.A)
    {
        tx = "0010";
        serialPort1.Write(tx);
    }
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.D)
    {
        tx = "0001";
        serialPort1.Write(tx);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.W & e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.A)`? you're probably mean `if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.W && e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.A)`. Notice that when `e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.W` is `true`, `e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.A` is `false` and vice versa. That means that whole expression always returns `false`

Comment: @MadSorcerer `&` is [fine for this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) in C#.

Comment: but the condition is still never returns `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//DetectCombination like this:
    public DateTime PrevPress { get; set; }
    public DateTime CurrentPress { get; set; }
    public string PrevKey { get; set; }

    private void SEND_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        string keycomb = DetectCombination(e.KeyChar.toString);
    }
    public string DetectCombination(string currentKey)
    {
        CurrentPress = DateTime.Now;
        if(CurrentPress.CompareTo(PrevPress) < //100ms)
        {
            PrevKey+=currentKey;
        }
        else
        {
            PrevKey = currentKey;
            PrevPress = CurrentPress;
        }
        return PrevKey;
    }
```

//One more function will be required to apply your logic, but seems like you'd take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

A and W can never be truly pressed at the same time, no matter how much you try they will be off.  One always happens before the other.  Keypress fires for each key press.

You need to subscribe  to keydown and keyup.  When keydown happens record the key that was pressed in a hashlist.  When keyup happens check if the hashlist contains A and W, then send 1010.

Always check your highest key combination first, before processing shorter key combinations, and then single keys.  It's important to do it in Keyup because the user needs a chance to press all the keys down that go together and hold them.  If you tried to do it in keydown you'd have the same problem (always 1 at a time).

Comment: +1 Also note that in his combinations, specific "bits" still correspond to W/S/A/D. A simpler implementation with fast response would be to maintain the state of each of the four, adjusting appropriately with keydown and keyup, and if any of them change build the string of '1' and '0' from the stored state and send it. This would not need a hashlist and would not need special logic for combinations.

Comment: @JasonC good advice.  Also I noticed another bug with it.  When checking the key combinations, fire it on key up, but check keys that are still down as the user can't let off all the keys at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Occurs when **a** character. space or backspace key is pressed while the
>   control has focus.

This event handler is fired once per key. This means that this line

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.W & e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.A)
```

Will always evaluate to `false`. Not to mention the fact that a variable cannot be multiple values at once.

Therefore if you want to detect multiple keys, you will have to do it another way. One way could be, every time you press a key, store the value in a buffer, first checking if the buffer already has a value, and if so, modify the sending value accordingly. Then have a timer running, so every time the timer elapses it will send whatever data is in the buffer, then clear it.

Comment: That line will always evaluate to false but not because of the way the event handler is fired. It will always evaluate to false because a variable cannot have two different values at the same time. Also a better strategy would be to track key down and key up events to see if they are actually pressed at the same time, without a time; otherwise it's not so good for a game where you might just want to press 'W' then a separate 'A' quickly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

A and W can never be truly pressed at the same time,first check W and then check A,finally pass value 1010

if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.W)

{

```
   if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.A)
    { 
      tx = "1010";
      serialPort1.Write(tx);
    }
```

}